# Traveling to Dubai from Egypt with an expired Egyptian visa

Tags: visas, legal, uae, egypt

My sister is going to give me a visit visa for me to visit her in Dubai. I'm here in Egypt with a tourist visa which has expired several months ago (April 2015).

My question is can I go to Dubai leaving from Egypt with an an expired Egyptian tourist visa? Will there be any problem if I leave Egypt?

Comment: Your tourist visa is for which country ? Are you an Egyptian citizen ?

Comment: Do you mean you are in Egypt on an expired visa?

Comment: You'll have to pay a fine while exiting; that's about it.

Comment: My tourist visa is for Egypt. It's been expired last April 2015. Thanx

Comment: And I'm planning to go to Dubai January next year. So i want to know if I can go from here to DUbai? Thanx

Comment: Rephrased the question to render it more clear and thus answerable.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not Dubai, **your problem will be leaving Egypt**.  However, accordingly to [anecdotal evidence](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/africa/topics/overstaying-an-egyptian-tourist-visa?page=1), overstays of "several months" can be settled with a fine of LE 150 paid at the airport on departure.  I'm not sure if a half a year is too much, but I would definitely go the airport nice and early, and with a large stack of cash on hand.

Answer (score 0):

You will pay penalty fees while departure, in the passport control officer will direct you to pay the fees. You need to plan for more time before your flight.

Comment: References?  Links? Something?

Comment: This just duplicates the existing answer, except with less detail and no references.